# Implementing basic next/previous picture

Tags: atk4

I'm trying to convert the Adjuster example mentioned here: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/view/interactive
into a View that is able to show me the next/previous picture of a list of given images.
I guess the number in the example could be an index into an array of pictures.
I'm just not sure how to provide the list of pictures, when all the code is put in init() for the View, so no way to give it the picturelist before that...
Should I use memorize/recall for this list also to prevent it getting lost upon reload ? 
is there another example that might help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you what you are doing can be much easier done with a classic JavaScript Lightbox script. You would supply it list of images and it would show one full-screen.

If not, you can use this:
https://gist.github.com/romaninsh/7217119

This will give you slides similar to the ones on http://agiletech.ie/

Be advised that this code is a little old.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it, and see what has to change for 4.2